# Oracle Support Tips & Tricks

Tags: oracle, vendor-support

How can My Oracle Support (Metalink) be used effectively?

What are your secret hints to this system? What saved you the most time?

Comment: Not sure if this question is on-topic. BTW: Tipps is spelled tips :) ( sorry for nit-picking - I'd have edited if I could)

Comment: I think this question is extremely on topic, as metalink is incredibly difficult to use.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overlook the "weird error lookup" tools. Most of the generic errors in oracle (i.e. ora-00600) have a lookup tool in Metalink that given the right parameters from the dump may actually help you more than you would realize.